# Redshift Join VS. Union with Group By

Tags: sql, performance, join, union, amazon-redshift

Let's say I would like to pull the fields dim,a,b,c,d from 2 tables which one contains a,b and the other contains c,d.

I'm wondering if there's a preferred way (between the following) to do it - **Performance wise**:

## 1:

```
select t1.dim,a,b,c,d
from 
(select dim,sum(a) as a,sum(b)as b from t1 group by dim)t1 
join 
(select dim,sum(c) as c,sum(d) as d from t2 group by dim)t2 
on t1.dim=t2.dim;
```

## 2:

```
select dim,sum(a) as a,sum(b) as b,sum(c) as c,sum(d) as d
from 
(
select dim,a,b,null as c, null as d from t1
union
select dim,null as a, null as b, c, d from t2
)a
group by dim
```

Of course when handling a large amount of data (5-30M records at the final query).

Thanks!

Comment: Check the execution plan for both queries.

Comment: Thanks @Viki888 but I'm asking in general, this is just an example.

Comment: As Gordon mentions below you definitely want `union all` instead of `union` since you're not concerned about duplicates. Without testing a specific case I'd go with number 2 for Redshift. Since it's a distributed columnar store you have to move the same data to the compute node regardless but the second case doesn't have the overhead of the join. The sum is a fast in memory operation. But yeah...query execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The first method filters would any `dim` values that are not in both tables.  `union` is inefficient.  So, neither is appealing.

I would go for:

```
select dim, sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c, sum(d) as d
from (select dim, a, b, null as c, null as d from t1
      union all
      select dim, null as a, null as b, c, d from t2
     ) a
group by dim;
```

You could also pre-aggregate the values in each subquery.  Or use `full outer join` for the first method.

Comment: Thanks Gordon but my main question was if there's a clearly preferred way to run the query performance wise.  Let's say that the join doesn't drop any rows and that the final result for both queries is exactly the same.  In this case,  which one woukd be redshift's favorite?

Comment: @evyamiz . . . You should test the different methods on your data.  However, getting the query to be accurate is quite important.